# Gorm cannot create table has foreignKey

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

This my struct. I need 1 restaurant can have many location

```
type Restaurant struct {
    ID        uint                  `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement" json:"id"`
    Name      string                `json:"name"`
    Merchants []*Merchant           `gorm:"many2many:restaurant_merchants" json:"-"`
    Locations []*RestaurantLocation `json:"locations"`
}

type RestaurantLocation struct {
    ID           uint        `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement" json:"id"`
    Name         string      `json:"name"`
    Address      string      `json:"address"`
    Lat          float64     `json:"lat"`
    Lng          float64     `json:"lng"`
    RestaurantID uint        `json:"-"`
    Restaurant   *Restaurant `json:"restaurant"`
    Menus        []*Menu     `json:"menus"`
    Orders       []*Order    `json:"orders"`
}
```

And I cannot bind data in `&location` model `RestaurantLocation`
But I logged what data received
`{"address":"address 1 test","lat":18.8086557500438,"lng":98.97084815886596,"restaurant_id":1,"name":"branch 1 test"}`

Comment: I ensure in table restaurant has id: 1

Comment: I use ShouldBindJSON function to bind.